# Multiple lists in the same navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm currently trying to understand how stumbleupons navigationbar works by recreating it.

I'm using 3 lists in 1  like this:

```
<nav role="navigation">
        <ul id="rightnav">
            <li></li><!--
             --><li></li><!--
             --><li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="leftnav">
            <li></li><!--
             --><li></li><!--
             --><li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="centernav">
            <li id="dislike">&nbsp;</li><!--
             --><li id="stumble">STUMBLE</li><!--
             --><li id="like">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is what I've got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/litari/yCT4D/1/

the three lists wont line up propperly no matter what I try.
I'm quite new to CSS so it's probably something obvious I'm missing.

I would also appreciate any additional comments on my css. If it sucks, let me know (and let me know WHY. I want to get better!) :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7cvc4/)**

```
ul
{
   list-style-type: none; 
}
nav{
    height: 30px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
#lefttnav{
    float:left;
}
#centernav{
    display:inline-block;   
}
#rightnav{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below CSS:

```
#leftnav, #centernav, #rightnav{
    display: inline;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yCT4D/4/)

Answer (score -1):

Use this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/yCT4D/6/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <div align='left' style='margin-left: -10px;'>
        <a href='#'>item 1</a>
        <a href='#'>item 1</a>
        </div>
        <div align='center' style='margin-top: -18px;'>
        <a href='#'>item 1</a>
        <a href='#'>item 1</a>
        </div>
        <div align='right' style='margin-top: -18px; margin-right: 15px;'>
        <a href='#'>item 1</a>
        <a href='#'>item 1</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```